How to send file data to server action using next-safe-action & react-hook-form
I've created an input and received the file, I can see the data stored in formData, but when I send them to the server-action I receive this error:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Server Actions. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.
and the error marks executeCreate, in here:
  `async function onSubmit() {
    if (product) {
      await executeUpdate(form.getValues());
    } else {
      await executeCreate(form.getValues());
    }
    router.refresh(); // could grab a new timestamp from db
    // reset dirty fields
    form.reset(form.getValues());
  }`

and here is it's definition:
 const {
    executeAsync: executeCreate,
    result: createResult,
    isExecuting: isCreating,
  } = useAction(createProductAction, {
    onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
      toast({
        variant: "default",
        title: "Success! ",
        description: data?.message,
      });
    },
    onError: ({ error }) => {
      toast({
        variant: "destructive",
        title: "Error",
        description: "Error Creating Product",
      });
    },
  });

this approach only is problematic with files and File type, and I want to know if there is a way to use next-safe-action if not I can use the default approach using useEffect to show the result

You can use next-safe-action . and few other packages with it. Let me know if you want CODE

If I didn't want the answer, I would not ask, so Yes
